# The Riemann integral of a non-negative function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Suppose $g : [−1,1] \to\mathbb R$ is [Riemann integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) on $[−1,1], g(x) ≥ 0$ for all $x ∈ [−1,1]$, and $g(0) > 0$.
Does it follow that $\int_{-1}^{1} g > 0$?

I tried proving that it is true by the definition of Riemann integration. Let $P={x_0,x_1,...,x_n}$ be a partition of $[-1,1]$. So, the Upper sum $U(g,P)=\sum M_i\Delta x_i$ where $M_i= Sup \{g(x): x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]\}$. As $g(0)>0$ and $g(x)$ is non-negative in this interval, we may write $U(g,P)>0$. But my doubt is, this implies that the upper integral $U(g)=Inf \{U(g,P), P$ is a partition of $[-1,1]\}\geq 0$. How do we get the strict inequality?

Comment: Let $g(x)=0$ for all $x \ne 0$, and let $g(0)=1$. This is still Riemann integrable, but the integral is zero.

Comment: For this to be true, you also need $g$ continuous.

Comment: There are two theorems related to strict inequality: 

- If $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is non-negative, Riemann integrable and continuous at some point $x_0\in [a,b]$ where $g(x_0)>0$, then $\int_a^bg>0$.

 - If $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a Riemann-integrable function strictly positive on $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^bg>0$.

The second follows from the first once we show that Riemann-integrability implies that there exists one point of continuity (actually Lebesgue's theorem tells us much more: the set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero, so there are actually infinitely many points of continuity)

Comment: A bit of a feeble problem (as Mr AngryBird's comment illustrates).   More deserving of attention might be this.  Let $f:[a,b]\to [0,\infty)$ be Riemann integrable and write
$E = \{ x\in [a,b]:  f(x)>0\}$.  State necessary and sufficient conditions on $E$ in order to conclude that  $\int_a^b f(x)\,   dx=0$.  *Hint*: (i) $E$ finite is sufficient, but not necessary. (ii) $E$ contains no interval is necessary, but not sufficient.  (Not so intriguing for advanced students, but worth some thinking for novices to integration theory.)